# Form based authentication is not working in tomcat 6.0

Tags: java, authentication, tomcat, forms-authentication

I'm using Tomcat 6.0 as a webserver, and I want to know how can I run login page over https protocol?

I've implemented form based authentication correctly with **NONE** as value in  tag, but when I changed <**transport-gurantee>** tag with the value **CONFIDENTIAL**, my browser is not able to display the page and  returning an error:

**Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:8443.**

Could anyone please tell me why it is not happening with NONE as value, and how can I overcome from this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your Tomcat server is listening on port 8443, and that you have an SSL cert for "localhost" setup correctly.

Actually, you probably should be using the machine's DNS name / IP address rather than localhost / 127.0.0.1.